# Штрафы в Adwords API

Tags: google-adwords

Мне нужно чётко понять, что значит нарушение правил. В руководстве по Adwords API не достаточно конкретно описано, что значит нарушить правила. Виды нарушений. Допустим я сделал триллион запросов(утрировано). Мне нужно чётко понимать, что мне не выпишут штраф десятки тысяч долларов без предупреждения и сразу. Помогите разобраться.

Answer (score 0):

[Правила](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/ratesheet?hl=ru).

> Штрафы за несоблюдение требований вычисляются следующим образом:
>
> - Сумма штрафа определяется по количеству операций или загрузок отчетов    за предыдущие 30 дней. За каждые 25 000 операций или 25 000
>     загрузок    отчетов начисляется 1 доллар США. Оплачивается наибольшая
>     из этих    двух сумм. Окончательная сумма округляется до 1000 долларов
>     США (если    она меньше) и ограничена 25 000 долларов США. Общая сумма
>     штрафа за    несоблюдение правил не будет превышать 50 000 долларов
>     США за весь    период.
> - Штрафы за несоблюдения правил должны оплачиваться полностью, иначе    доступ будет изменен на базовый или заблокирован.

Comment: Это я всё читал. Но ответа здесь нет. Несоблюдение требований написано. А где эти требования описаны? Виды нарушений. Что считается нарушением правил?

Comment: @artyr ну вот же требования https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/requirements?hl=ru